# Feynman diagram for semileptonic decay of neutral kaon

Tags: feynman-diagrams, neutrinos, pions, leptons

I am unsure how to draw a feynman diagram for a reaction that occurs as follows

$$ K^0  --> l^+\nu_l\pi^- $$

Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know which quarks are inside kaons and pions?

Comment: The long-lived neutral kaon is called the KL ("K-long"), decays primarily into three pions, and has a mean lifetime of 5.18×10−8 s.
The short-lived neutral kaon is called the KS ("K-short"), decays primarily into two pions, and has a mean lifetime 8.958×10−11

Comment: Hint: the strange antiquark will turn to an up antiquark by the emission of a *W* +.

Comment: @Rick Isn't your comment a deeply irrelevant red herring that confuses the OP?

Comment: No it was a way to prompt more thought...  there are a lot of Feynman Diagrams of Kaon decays online.  http://www.hep.ph.ic.ac.uk/~dauncey/will/lecture16.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Drawing the most appropriate Feynman diagram can be a little tricky sometimes. I find it best to work backwards with the general rule of thumb being to try to minimize the number of vertices. We know that the lepton pair $l^{+}, \nu_{l}$ must come from a $W^{+}$ boson as that's the only mediator that conserves charge and can violate flavor. Since we are dealing with the $K^{0}$ meson whose quark configuration is $d \bar{s}$ and a daughter meson $\pi^{-}$ whose configuration is $d \bar{u}$, we notice that both the $K^{0}$ and $\pi^{-}$ contain a $d$-quark. This $d$-quark will act as a spectator quark (will remain unchanged in the scattering process). Now all that's left is recognizing that $W$ bosons connect the positively charged quarks to the negative and vice verse with the exception of not connecting particles to antiparticles. So for an example a $q^{+} \longrightarrow q^{-} + W^{+}$ where the positive superscript is merely to denote a positive charge and the negative denotes negative charge.

Hopefully that's sufficient information to guide you to the proper Feynman Diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Because neutral currents have not been observed and flavor changing can only be done with the emission of W bosons the strange antiquark will decay to an up antiquark and W- boson . The W- boson will decay to an electron and an antielectron neutrino. The pion formed by the up antiquark and the down quark will decay to a neutral pion and a W- boson.The W- boson will decay to an electron and an electron antineutrino.The neutral pion will decay to 2 gamma rays and all is left is 2 electrons and 2 electron antineutrinos and some light.